# Using batch file to overwrite a file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Basically I'm just trying to have my batch file update my Access front end file on startup. My batch file is in the code below. I can't get this to work properly because of the spaces in my folder and file names. Also the C:/Warehouse Management Systems folder is already on the computer that needs to be updated.

```
md "c:\Warehouse Management Systems"
del "c:\Warehouse Management Systems\Warehouse Management Systems.accde"
copy \\FS2\Users\Warehouse Management\Warehouse Management Systems\Warehouse 
Management Front End\Warehouse Management Systems.accde c:\Warehouse Management Systems
c:\Warehouse Management Systems\Warehouse Management Systems.accde"
```

Comment: Don't put excessive code into comments- it's nearly unredable without line breaks. Instead [edit] your question to contain the code

Comment: Your last line contains a double-quote at the end of the destination file, but not at the start of the destination file, and not around the source file (which also contains spaces)

Comment: So your last line is probably intended to be `copy "\\FS2\Users\Warehouse Management\Warehouse Management Systems\Warehouse 
Management Front End\Warehouse Management Systems.accde c:\Warehouse Management Systems"
"c:\Warehouse Management Systems\Warehouse Management Systems.accde"`